# bash getting a fd of a pipe

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

Why does the following not work?

```
exec 3<|cat $0
```

The idea is to get file-descriptor (3) of a pipe (| cat $0).

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? That sequence has no meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot mix *exec* and pipes that way. It seems what you need is a process substitution:

```
$ exec 3< <(cat /etc/hosts)
$ grep ftp <&3
209.85.41.143 ftp.archlinux.org
```

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17601.html#REDIR1

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

Comment: Of course, this serves as a generic example, if you need only a "cat", you can write directly: "exec 3< myfile".

Answer (score 0):

```
exec 3<>$0
while read -u 3 line;
do
  grep ftp $line;
done
exec 3>&-;
```

Comment: this makes 3 a fd of $0 file - not a pipe. See the answer.